# Strategies for multi-platform (not just cross-platform) development of the same product line?

Tags: android, ios, macos, cross-platform, multiplatform

I am here to ask for some high-level strategies for maintaining development of a multi-platform product line, in a startup environment.  Think in terms of what a company like DropBox does to have an iOS version, an Android, a Mac, a Windows and Linux version.  I am interested in all aspects: source control, team organization, testing, the works.  An over-all best practice strategy for ending up with killer code on all targeted platforms.

I don't have experience maintaining mature projects in several platforms, so I wonder what advice you have for me.  In my specific case, the question is relevant to Android and iOS development, but the questoin is really far more general.  I asked that question with my initial impressions here: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3484074 though I guess I included too much of my own train of thought to be useful.  So forget my impressions: what is your experience?  What works best?

Thanks for all your feedback!

Comment: I cannot give actual advice, seeing as I have yet to do this. But I am embarking on generally the same quest. What I will be doing is developing the application in tandem, spending time duplicating what I did on one platform on another, and keeping all the code in one repository in different folders. I have yet to see if this works, so take what you will from that.

Answer (score 0):

Really you want to start with continuous integration.  Get a build setup where you just push to your repository and it gets built, tested and packaged everywhere.

Personally I have setup a VMWare server which contains many buildbot master/slaves which compile my git repository overnight.  In the morning I can verify that everything build and if not then I make the correction there and then to the code.

Certainly pick a cross-platform toolkit rather that re-writing code.  Qt is our base and that's going to help us provide 95% common code across our builds.

The trick is really to automate/script as much as you can.  When you grow you're not wasting time manually compiling and packaging 5 different platforms.